# How to get a list of task filter by "tag" in the TargetProcess REST API?

Tags: rest, targetprocess

How to get a list of task filter by "tag" in the TargetProcess REST API?

PS: I tried to added the TargetProcess tags but SO didn't let me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
yourtargetprocess/api/v1/Bugs?where=Tags contains 'yourTag'
```